# Need to return coincidence matrix between two channels of time-stamped events

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a coincidence matrix between energy events measured by detectors in two channels. "Coincidence" is to say that the events occur within a user-specified timing window of each other. The data are currently stored in a pandas dataframe of the following format with fake sample data:

```
Energy   Timestamp  Channel
___________________________
6        103        1
7         70        2
4        110        2
8        205        2 
2        219        1
3        333        1
5        300        1
9        350        2
```

I need the data in the following format such that, if a user were to select a timing window of 20, the resulting coincidence matrix would be:

```
Channel 1 Energy:   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
Channel 2 Energy:_________________________________________
                 1| 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 2| 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 3| 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 4| 0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
                 5| 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 6| 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 7| 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 8| 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
                 9| 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
                10| 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Where now only the events that meet the condition:

```
 Event1_Timestamp < Event2_Timestamp + Timing window & Event1_Timestamp > Event2_Timestamp - Timing window
```

are preserved in the coincidence matrix, and all noncoincident events are discarded.

I have tried:

```
df2 = df.merge(df, on="Timestamp")
df3 = pd.crosstab(df2.Energy_x, df2.Energy_y)
```

but there are a few problems with this output. It looks for exact matches in the timestamp rather than a timing window range, and it only lists the energies that appear, rather than a linearly spaced range of all possible energies (0-8192 energy bins). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try using `pd.merge_asof` and `pd.crosstab`:

Where df,

```
   Energy  Timestamp  Channel
0       6        103        1
1       7         70        2
2       4        110        2
3       8        205        2
4       2        219        1
5       3        333        1
6       5        300        1
7       9        350        2
```

Then,

```
df_out = pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('Timestamp'), 
                       df.sort_values('Timestamp'), 
                       on='Timestamp', 
                       allow_exact_matches=False,
                      tolerance=20)

pd.crosstab(df_out['Energy_x'], 
            df_out['Energy_y']).reindex(index=np.arange(1,11),
                                        columns=np.arange(1,11), 
                                        fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Energy_y  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
Energy_x                                        
1          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4          0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
5          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9          0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```